# Install Keras from Git Clone [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, keras

i wanna install keras in my sever OVH, so i've cloned the package from GitHub, but when i run the installation from the keras repertory with the CMD : python3  keras/tools/pip_package/setup.py install
it return the error : [image: capture]

thank you

Comment: have you tried installing using `sudo`?

Comment: there is no sudo in OVH server only python or pip

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have administrative permission to the system. Using Sudo may help. Or trying to change the install directory to local storage and add it to your PATH.

Comment: i m working in the OVH server that s why i cant use the sudo , and i m currently connected to the server

Answer (score 1):

I see at the top you have tried to run `setup.py` if you have `pip`, try `python3 -m pip install keras/tools/pip_package/`